# CoffeeScript, When to use fat arrow (=>) over arrow (->) and vice versa

Tags: coffeescript, arrow-functions

When building a class in CoffeeScript, should all the instance method be defined using the `=>` ("fat arrow") operator and all the static methods being defined using the `->` operator?

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Comment: See also this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17431824/517371

Answer (score 165, accepted):

No, that's not the rule I would use.

The major use-case I've found for the fat-arrow in defining methods is when you want to use a method as a callback and that method references instance fields:

```
class A
  constructor: (@msg) ->
  thin: -> alert @msg
  fat:  => alert @msg

x = new A("yo")
x.thin() #alerts "yo"
x.fat()  #alerts "yo"

fn = (callback) -> callback()

fn(x.thin) #alerts "undefined"
fn(x.fat)  #alerts "yo"
fn(-> x.thin()) #alerts "yo"
```

As you see, you may run into problems passing a reference to an instance's method as a callback if you don't use the fat-arrow. This is because the fat-arrow binds the instance of the object to `this` whereas the thin-arrow doesn't, so thin-arrow methods called as callbacks as above can't access the instance's fields like `@msg` or call other instance methods. The last line there is a workaround for cases where the thin-arrow has been used.

Comment: What do you do when you want to use the `this` that would be called from the thin arrow, but also the instance variables that you would get with the fat arrow?

Comment: As I said "The last line there is a workaround for cases where the thin-arrow has been used."

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Suppose that the default scope of the callback has `this` set to a variable that I want to use. However, I also want to reference a class method, so I want `this` to refer to the class as well. I can only choose between one assignment for `this`, so what is the best way to be able to use both variables?

Comment: @AndrewMao you should probably post a full question on this site rather than having me answer in a comment :)

Comment: It's ok, question is not that important. But I just wanted to clarify that it was not what you were referring to in your last line of code.

Comment: Here's a practical example: http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/jquery/callback-bindings-jquery

Comment: So `fn(-> x.thin())` is the same as `fn(x.thin.call(x))`?

Comment: @Zaz definitely not! But the comments section here is not the right place to get this question answered...

Answer (score 14):

A point not mentioned in other answers that is important to note is that binding functions with fat arrow when it is not necessary can lead to unintended results such as in this example with a class we'll just call DummyClass.

```
class DummyClass
    constructor : () ->
    some_function : () ->
        return "some_function"

    other_function : () =>
        return "other_function"

dummy = new DummyClass()
dummy.some_function() == "some_function"     # true
dummy.other_function() == "other_function"   # true
```

In this case the functions do exactly what one might expect and there seems to be no loss to using fat arrow, but what happens when we modify the DummyClass prototype after it's already been defined (e.g. changing some alert or changing the output of a log):

```
DummyClass::some_function = ->
    return "some_new_function"

DummyClass::other_function = ->
    return "other_new_function"

dummy.some_function() == "some_new_function"   # true
dummy.other_function() == "other_new_function" # false
dummy.other_function() == "other_function"     # true
```

As we can see overriding our previously defined function of the prototype causes some_function to be correctly overwritten but other_function remains the same on instances as fat arrow has caused other_function from the class to be bound to all instances so instances won't refer back to their class to find a function

```
DummyClass::other_function = =>
    return "new_other_new_function"

dummy.other_function() == "new_other_new_function"    # false

second_dummy = new DummyClass()
second_dummy.other_function() == "new_other_new_function"   # true
```

Even fat arrow won't work as fat arrow only causes the function to be bound to new instances (which do gain the new functions as one would expect).

However this leads to some problems, what if we need a function (e.g. in the case of switching a logging function to an output box or something) that will work on all existing instances (including event handlers) [as such we can't use fat arrows in original definition] but we still need access to internal attributes in an event handler [the exact reason we used fat arrows not thin arrows].

Well the simplest way to accomplish this is to merely include two functions in the original class definition, one defined with a thin arrow which does the operations that you wish to execute, and another defined with a fat arrow that does nothing but call the first function for example:

```
class SomeClass
    constructor : () ->
        @data = 0
    _do_something : () ->
        return @data
    do_something : () =>
        @_do_something()

something = new SomeClass()
something.do_something() == 0     # true
event_handler = something.do_something
event_handler() == 0              # true

SomeClass::_do_something = -> return @data + 1

something.do_something() == 1     # true
event_handler() == 1              # true
```

So when to use thin/fat arrows can be summed up fairly easy in four ways:

1. Thin arrow alone functions should be used when the both conditions are mett:

   - The method will never be passed by reference including event_handlers e.g. you never have a case such as: some_reference = some_instance.some_method; some_reference()
   - AND the method should be universal over all instances so if the prototype function changes so does the method over all instances
2. Fat arrow alone functions should be used when the following condition is met:

   - The method should be bound precisely to the instance at instance creation and remain permanently bound even if the function definition changes for the prototype, this includes all cases where the function should be an event handler and the event handler behaviour should be consistent
3. Fat arrow function which directly calls a thin arrow function should be used when the following conditions are met:

   - The method is required to be called by reference such as an event handler
   - AND the functionality may change in future affecting existing instances by replacing the thin arrow function
4. Thin arrow function which directly calls a fat arrow (not demonstrated) function should be used when the following conditions are met:

   - The fat arrow function must be always attached to the instance
   - BUT the thin arrow function may change (even to a new function which doesn't use the original fat arrow function)
   - AND the thin arrow function is never needed to be passed by reference

In all approaches it must be considered in the case where the prototype functions might be changed whether or not behaviour for specific instances will behave correctly for example although a function is defined with a fat arrow its behaviour may not be consistent within an instance if it calls a method that is changed within the prototype

Answer (score 9):

Usually, `->` is fine.

```
class Foo
  @static:  -> this
  instance: -> this

alert Foo.static() == Foo # true

obj = new Foo()
alert obj.instance() == obj # true
```

Note how the static method return the class object for `this` and the instance returns the instance object for `this`.

What's happening is that the invocation syntax is providing the value of `this`.  In this code:

```
foo.bar()
```

`foo` will be the context of the `bar()` function by default.  So it just sorta works how you want.  You only need the fat arrow when you call these function in some other way that does not use the dot syntax for invocation.

```
# Pass in a function reference to be called later
# Then later, its called without the dot syntax, causing `this` to be lost
setTimeout foo.bar, 1000

# Breaking off a function reference will lose it's `this` too.
fn = foo.bar
fn()
```

In both of those cases, using a fat arrow to declare that function would allow those to work.  But unless you are doing something odd, you usually don't need to.

So use `->` until you really need `=>` and never use `=>` by default.

Comment: This will fail if you do: `x = obj.instance; alert x() == obj # false!`

Comment: Of course it will, but that would fall under "doing it wrong".  I have now edited my answer and explain just when a `=>` would be needed on the static/instance methods of a class.

Comment: Nitpick: `// is not a CoffeeScript comment` whereas `# is a CoffeeScript comment`.

Comment: How is `setTimeout foo.bar, 1000` "doing it wrong"? Using a fat-arrow is much nicer than using `setTimeout (-> foo.bar()), 1000` IMHO.

Comment: @nicolaskruchten There is a case for that syntax in `setTimeout`, of course.  But your first comment is somewhat contrived and doesn't reveal a legitimate use case, but simply reveals how it might break.  I'm simply saying that you shouldn't use a `=>` unless you need it for a good reason, especially on class instance methods where it has a performance cost of creating a new function needing to be bound on instantiation.

Answer (score 5):

just an example for unstanding the fat arrow

not works: (@canvas undefined)

```
class Test
  constructor: ->
    @canvas = document.createElement 'canvas'
    window.addEventListener 'resize', ->
      @canvas.width = window.innerWidth
      @canvas.height = window.innerHeight
```

works: (@canvas defined)

```
class Test
  constructor: ->
    @canvas = document.createElement 'canvas'
    window.addEventListener 'resize', =>
      @canvas.width = window.innerWidth
      @canvas.height = window.innerHeight
```