# When building classes in coffeescript, is there ever a reason to not use the fat arrow for the instance methods?

Tags: memory-management, coffeescript, arrow-functions

When building classes in coffeescript, is there ever a reason to **not** use the fat arrow for  instance methods?

Edit:
Ok then! Great reply! :)  
 To sum up, the problems are:   
- Takes more memory  
- Inability to patch  
- Begs question, why is it used for this method?  
Convention:
- Be explicit when binding functions.  
- Declare fat arrowed methods in the constructor.  
- Use as much as you want, just not in class declarations.

Comment: maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965855/coffeescript-when-to-use-fat-arrow-over-arrow-and-vice-versa?rq=1

Comment: not using the fat arrow when you don't need it is lighter. Not sure if it matters much, though.

Comment: So it's just a matter of performance?

Comment: Yes. Also it avoids unintended consequences. You should always know why you are adding something to the default behavior. Later in your project you will not remember that everything is bound using the fat arrow and you will chase bugs that otherwise would never have happened.

Comment: also sometimes it could be useful to use a instance as a closure object and give a method as a callback to another method.

Comment: This must be the most apt use I've heard for "begs the question" and its corresponding fallacy in computer programming!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, there are reasons to not use the fat arrows always. In fact i'd argue in favour of *never* using fat-arrowed methods :)

Thin-arrow and fat-arrow methods are conceptually different things. The former are compiled to the expected prototype-based JS code; the methods belong to the class prototype. Fat-arrowed methods, on the other hand are associated with each instance in the constructor's code.

The most obvious disadvantage of always using fat-arrowed methods is that it makes each class instance take more memory (because it has more own properties) and its initialization be slower (because it has to create those bound functions and set them each time an instance is created).

Another disadvantage of using fat-arrow methods is that it breaks the usual expectation of what a method is: a method is no longer a function shared between the instances of a class, but it now is a separate function for each instance. This can cause problems if, for example, you'd want to modify a method after it has been defined in the class:

```
class Foo
  # Using fat-arrow method
  bar: (x) => alert x

# I have some Foos
foos = (new Foo for i in [1..3])

# And i want to path the bar method to add some logging. 
# This might be in another module or file entirely.
oldbar = Foo::bar
Foo::bar = (args...) ->
  console.log "Foo::bar called with", args
  oldbar.apply @, args

# The console.log will never be called here because the bar method 
# has already been bound to each instance and was not modified by 
# the above's patch.
foo.bar(i) for foo, i in foos
```

---

But the most important disadvantage in my opinion is more subjective: introducing fat-arrow methods makes the code (and the language) unnecessarily inconsistent and difficult to understand.

The code becomes more inconsistent because before introducing fat-arrow methods any time we see `<someProp>: <someVal>` in a class definition we know it means "declare a property named `<someProp>` with a value `<someVal>` in the class' prototype" (unless `<someProp> == 'constructor'`, which is a special case), it doesn't matter if `<someVal>` is a number or a function, it will just be a property in the prototype. With the introduction of fat-arrowed methods we now have another unnecessary special case: if `<someVal>` is a fat-arrowed function it will do a completely different thing than with any other value.

And there's another inconsistency: fat arrows [bind the `this` differently](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2492) when they are used in a method definition than when used anywhere else. Instead of preserving the outer `this` (which, inside a `class`, `this` is bound to the class constructor) the `this` inside a fat-arrowed method is an object that does not exist when the method is defined (i.e. an instance of the class).

If you mix thin-arrowed and fat-arrowed methods the code also becomes harder to follow because now every time a developer sees a fat-arrowed method they'll ask themselves why was it needed that for *that* method to be instance-bound. There's no immediate correlation between the method's declaration and where it's being used, which is where the need for fat-arrow method arises.

---

For all this, i'd recommend to never use fat-arrow methods. Prefer binding the method to an instance where it's going to be used instead of where the method is declared. For example:

```
# Be explicit about 'onClick' being called on 'someObject':
$someJQueryElement.on 'click', (e) -> someObject.onClick e

# Instead of:
$someJQueryElement.on 'click', someObject.onClick
```

Or, if you really want to bind the method on every instance on construction time, be explicit about that:

```
# Instead of fat-arrow methods:
class A
  constructor: ->
    @bar = 42
  foo: => 
    console.log @bar

# Assing the method in the constructor, just like you would 
# do with any other own property
class A
  constructor: ->
    @bar = 42
    @foo = => 
      console.log @bar
```

I think that in the second definition of `class A` it's much more explicit what is happening with the `foo` method than in the first definition.

Finally, notice that i'm not arguing against using the fat arrow at all. It's a very useful construct and i use it all the time for normal functions; i just prefer to avoid using it inside a `class` method definition :)

---

**Edit**: Another case against using fat-arrowed methods: decorator functions:

```
# A decorator function to profile another function.
profiled = (fn) ->
  (args...) ->
    console.profile()
    fn.apply @, args
    console.profileEnd()

class A
  bar: 10

  # This works as expected
  foo: profiled (baz) ->
    console.log "@bar + baz:", @bar + baz

  # This doesn't
  fatArrowedFoo: profiled (baz) =>
    console.log "@bar + baz:", @bar + baz

(new A).foo 5           # -> @bar + baz: 15
(new A).fatArrowedFoo 5 # -> @bar + baz: NaN
```

Comment: As for the decorator problem isn't that essentially the same problem as the inability to patch?

Comment: @SimonLandeholm, i see them as different problems. In the case of the decorator, the fat arrow doesn't do what is expected: instead of binding `this` to the instance once constructed, it binds it to the class constructor (the same happens if you just [add parens around the fat arrow function](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20A%0A%20%20a%3A%20%3D%3E%20%40c%0A%20%20b%3A%20%28%3D%3E%20%40c%29)). The inability to patch is a consequence of breaking the assumption that the `this` of a method is lazily bound (e.g. `[].slice.call(arguments)` is a common JS construct that relies on that assumption)

Comment: @epidemian great answer! Is there a way to access class properties from inside fat arrow functions, though? I see that `@bar` is undefined in your `fatArrowedFoo` function. I guess I'm asking for a way to have my cake and eat it too.. :)

Comment: @Goran_Mandic, you can use decorators on methods if you [bind them on the constructor](http://jsfiddle.net/eo98qma1/). Within the constructor, `this` will be an `A` instance, not `A` itself. But within the class definition, `this` is `A`, and Coffee has no way of knowing that a fat arrow function within some arbitrary expression (i.e., `profiled (baz) -> ...`) is meant to actually bind to `A` instances instead of to `A` itself. Hope it makes sense :P

Comment: It does, actually.. Now I realize, your answer contained the answer to my question as well, all along. I guess it was just a bit much to digest at once. Many thanks!

Comment: Upvoted for pointing out that it completely breaks prototypal inheritance, and creates a copy of the method for every instance. This alone is surprising enough behavior to avoid using fat-arrowed methods.

Comment: The only benefit to using fat-arrowed methods seem to be permanent binding to avoid having to worry about unbound methods used as callbacks, something you learn to avoid very early on in JavaScript by using anonymous invocations or `Function.prototype.bind`.

Answer (score 12):

Let me add my alternative view.

The elaborate reasons expressed by @epidemian for avoiding fat arrow are well and good, but consider the following:

- if you don't care (much, or at all) about the "underlying prototype-based JS code" generated by CoffeeScript, insofar as you are able to write consistent and bug-free CoffeeScript code;
- if you don't plan to write a gazillion tiny classes ala Java, that will spend 99% of their time calling each other's methods up and down the inheritance tree and get little work done in the process; said another way, if you recognize that performance-sensitive "inner loops" are not a good place to put method calls;
- if you don't plan on decorating, monkey-patching, or otherwise modifying your classes' methods at runtime;
- if you state your usage of fat arrow in a header comment, for the benefit of future developers working on your code;

then I would recommend to **always use fat arrow**, as a habit, both for methods and for anonymous functions.

This will make your CoffeeScript code simpler, safer and more intuitive, because you will know that **`this` and `@` always refer to the current object whose method you are defining**, as in most other programming languages, independently of whoever will be calling your functions and methods at runtime.

Stated more formally, fat arrow makes the `this` keyword (and its shorthand `@`) fully lexically scoped, like any other identifier. Programming language history shows that lexical scoping is the most intuitive and less error-prone way to scope identifiers. That's why it became the standard behaviour for all new languages a long time ago.

If you choose this path, **thin arrow becomes the exception**, and a useful one at that. You will use it to prepare those particular callbacks where you need `this` to refer to something defined at runtime by the caller, instead of your own object. This is a counter-intuitive meaning of `this`, but some JS libraries need this kind of behavior in user-supplied functions. The thin arrow will then serve to highlight those pieces of code. If I remember correctly, jQuery usually provides everything you need in the function arguments, so you can ignore its artificial `this`, but other libraries are not as benevolent.

NB: CoffeeScript 1.6.1 has a bug related to fat arrow methods, so you should avoid that. Previous and later versions should be ok.

### Performance

When used as a regular (anonymous) function, fat arrow does not add any overhead. In method declarations [it does add a **tiny** RAM and CPU overhead](http://nesbot.com/2012/1/20/CoffeeScript-why-is-function-binding-not-the-default) (really tiny: a few nanoseconds and a few bytes of RAM for each method call, and the latter disappears on engines with tail-call optimization.)

IMHO the language clarity and safety fat arrow gives in exchange is enough reason to tolerate and even welcome the small overhead. Many other CoffeeScript idioms add their own tiny overhead to the generated code (for loops, etc.) with the purpose of making the language behaviour more consistent and less error-prone. Fat arrow is no different.

Comment: hmm, I am not sure if I really would recommend your approach - superficially it seems correct - absolutely so. However I think that your specified precondition concerning monkey patching etc. is one that is unattainable in reality will cause troubles. Apart from that - a very interesting approach. Maybe it would have been kind if you had upvoted my question and answer if you already link to it ;-)

Comment: I believe it would depend heavily on the kind of project. On a medium to big project (10k to Ms of lines of code), or one that aims to become such, having this kind of consistency is a Good Thing. Knowing that each `@` in whomever's class always means "an attribute of the current instance of the class being defined" is invaluable. Not surprisingly, monkey patching and other dynamic code changes are usually frowned upon on such projects, for the same reason: it makes it harder (slower) to understand code you didn't write, so in the end it costs more. (upvoted, sorry about that)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm actually doing pretty much exactly this in the web app I'm writing. In particular, express expects a function that takes `(req, res, next)` as parameters, and then it's up to you to hold onto those objects while doing your processing. Given that most of what I want to do involves I/O, either to the db or to the web, I get lost in many nested callbacks. This is a way to bind `req` and `res` to any callback I need; it's super helpful.

Comment: @owensmartin you're welcome. In fact, I usually define my callbacks as fat-arrow methods, with a descriptive name, so that I can pass them to libraries as values: `someLibrary.doSomething 1, 2, @somethingWasDone` This turns my code into a linear sequence of method calls, without pyramids of nested `->` and the related variable scoping issues.

Comment: Even javascript creator says that using prototype inheritance is not good idea for today. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bo36MrBfTk4#t=1896

Comment: The bullet points essentially advocate using fat-arrowed methods insofar as you: (1) don't care about the compiled JS, (2) don't plan to architect your app around "a gazillion" different objects (read "in a decoupled way"), (3) don't mind breaking the prototype link, (4) are able to document what you've done.

Yeah, I don't think this approach is for me.