# Fat arrow repetition?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, arrow-functions

When I'm writing coffee script I tend to do this an awful lot (pseudo code):

```
$link.click (e) =>
  this._clicked(e)
```

Is there really not some way to bind transparently in CoffeeScript? I'd like to be able to do:

```
$link.click =this._clicked
```

or something, which would bind my this._clicked method, directly to the event, keeping its this pointer

any ideas?

**update**

_clicked would be defined as:

```
_clicked: (e) ->
  # some code
```

Comment: But your `_clicked` function was defined without the fat arrow? That may be the problem.

Comment: Oh.. I didn't even know I could do that? Fat arrow on a definition of a function - I'll look at this!

Comment: Bergi, Give me that as an answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: See also this discussion and my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17431824/517371

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing special with coffeescript. Just do

```
$link.click @_clicked
```

And then define `_clicked` as

```
_clicked: (e) =>
  # some code
```

It'll pass `this._clicked` as the handler for the click event of `link`.

You can pass any function as callbacks like this. The keypoint is to not execute the function (there are no () in `@_clicked`). A function in JS is a normal variable, which can be passed around as parameters to other functions.

With

```
$link.click ->
```

youre just passing a function to `.click` directly without storing it into a variable.

To keep the `this` you either [define `@_clicked` with a fat arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) or you use [JavaScripts `bind` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) which returns a function where `this` is bound to a certain value.

CoffeeScript is not adding any extra functionality to JavaScript. The Fat arrow just does a bind similar to the `bind` function from the link (if its used in a method definition of a class) or just does the `var _this = this` trick when a function is defined inside a function.

Comment: This isn't what I mean, though its a good point you can use @_clicked for functions, instead of this. I've just always seen it as a instance variable kind of thing (I know functions are, but it just feels different, coming from ruby)