# Convert coffeescript function to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am following this railscast https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltoPZEzmtJA but I don't use coffeescript.  I am trying to convert the coffeescript to javascript but I'm running into a problem.

**coffeescript**

```
jQuery ->
  new AvatarCropper()

class AvatarCropper
  constructor: ->
    $('#cropbox').Jcrop
      aspectRatio: 1
      setSelect: [0, 0, 600, 600]
      onSelect: @update
      onChange: @update

  update: (coords) =>
    $("#crop_x").val coords.x
    $("#crop_y").val coords.y
    $("#crop_w").val coords.w
    $("#crop_h").val coords.h
```

**js.erb file**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.crop-image').on('click', function () {
    $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
      aspectRatio: 1,
      setSelect: [0, 0, 100, 100],
      onSelect: update,
      onChange: update
    })
  });

  update: (function(_this) {
    return function(coords) {
      $('.user').val(coords.x);
      $('.user').val(coords.y);
      $('.user').val(coords.w);
      return $('.user').val(coords.h);
    };
  })(this)  

});
```

I didn't understand why he decided to make a class and thought it would be more complicated to convert the whole thing.  The trouble I'm having is the update function.  I just plugged his coffee script for the update function into a converter and used the output.  This is causing an error saying update is not defined.  Where am I going wrong?

Also bonus question: what's the point of him making a class here?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use this converter http://js2.coffee/

Comment: "Why to use classes, when you can write in C!"

Comment: I've been reading Javascript the good parts and the "construct a class method" is promoted in there with the advantage being privacy, i.e. exposing fewer  properties of an object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your syntax looks wrong... `:` is used to declare labelled statements.

This is a correct way. Declares an hoisted variable and assign a function ref. to it.
The function name can appear in expressed functions too, so it can refer itself intially using its name.

Using `var` the function variable should hoist, except the assign value.

```
/* there are various ways to declare a function */

function update(coords) {
    var $users = $('.user');
    $users.val(coords.x);
    $users.val(coords.y);
    $users.val(coords.w);
    return $users.val(coords.h);
}
```

Comment: sorry my code was wrong, the coords are supposed to be x,y,w,h I will change it..copied it wrong

Comment: also, in the railscast he made a point to say he's using the fat arrow..something about context, I'm not sure what this means.  Does your answer account for this?

Comment: Read: `https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/`

Comment: Thanks your answer seems to be working for me.  Any thoughts as to why make this whole thing a class like he did in the original coffeescript?

Comment: I think the fat arrow in this case might be a coffeescript specific thing..not sure.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965855/coffeescript-when-to-use-fat-arrow-over-arrow-and-vice-versa) is an SO question about it but I don't really understand it.

Comment: @user4584963 Classes make the code more efficient. Fat arrows are specified in ES6 and work in the today JavaScript.

Comment: My answer looks kinda wrong... The colon also define labels

Answer (score 1):

The point of a class:

- make it more easy to run the same task multiple times on different elements with less room for collisions.
- to help mentally organize your code

To convert, use a site like http://js2.coffee/

```
var AvatarCropper,
  bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };

jQuery(function() {
  return new AvatarCropper();
});

AvatarCropper = (function() {
  function AvatarCropper() {
    this.update = bind(this.update, this);
    $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
      aspectRatio: 1,
      setSelect: [0, 0, 600, 600],
      onSelect: this.update,
      onChange: this.update
    });
  }

  AvatarCropper.prototype.update = function(coords) {
    $("#crop_x").val(coords.x);
    $("#crop_y").val(coords.y);
    $("#crop_w").val(coords.w);
    return $("#crop_h").val(coords.h);
  };

  return AvatarCropper;

})();

// ---
// generated by coffee-script 1.9.2
```